# Switching from Java 1.7 to Java 1.6 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, java

I changed the JAVA_HOME and Path Variable pointing to my Java 1.6 Location from Java 1.7-> tried checking the version using **java -version**. It showed **Java 1.7**.

Next, tried deleting the Java 1.7 Installation and still version shows Java 1.7. Restarted the PC twice. Any ideas?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to add the Java *bin* dir to the *beginning* of your PATH instead of at the end.

Another option would be to delete `Windows\System32\java.exe`, so that the actual java.exe from the *bin* dir in your PATH is executed.

Comment: Eh, no. Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` (or the full path i.e. `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin`) to the very *beginning* of your PATH string.